# How to solve this calibration problem of National Instruments Elvis board?

Tags: measurement, calibration, instrumentation

I have NI Elvis II board and i am trying to calibrate my ELVIS II using the self calibrate option of MAX(measurement  & automation explorer). I have tried my best to follow the instructions given in chapter 4(calibration)of user manual. But despite multiple efforts, i couldn't get rid of this error. I have attached both snapshot of error and instructions on user manual calibration chapter

If this issue cannot be solved through this self calibration utility, then how can i calibrate it?What are the other feasible ways to calibrate it if we don't have enough budget to send it back to National Instruments for calibration?

As far as the reasons mentioned in snapshot are concerned, i am unable to properly understand the first two reasons and there is no apparent option in MAX that allows us to specify value of refrence signal for calibration purpose.

[image]
[image]

Comment: so, the error message gives potential reasons. You have certainly looked into them before asking here. What was the result of your investigations?

Comment: ah so, we need to talk about *understanding* the reasons. So, let's start with the first! What is unclear about that?

Comment: there is no explicit/apparent option available in MAX that allows us to specify value of refrence signal for calibration purpose.

Comment: That temperature reading tells me that something is broken.